# Finding nearest node inside trees

Tags: python, pandas, search, tree

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` contains nodes from trees. The table looks like this:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ index ║ color  ║  name  ║ head ║
╠═══════╬════════╬════════╬══════╣
║     0 ║ red    ║ Tom    ║    0 ║
║     1 ║ blue   ║ Lucy   ║    0 ║
║     2 ║ green  ║ Peter  ║    1 ║
║     3 ║ red    ║ Katy   ║    1 ║
║     4 ║ green  ║ Sam    ║    4 ║
║     5 ║ orange ║ Linda  ║    2 ║
║     6 ║ blue   ║ Robert ║    4 ║
║     7 ║ brown  ║ James  ║    6 ║
║     8 ║ red    ║ Betty  ║    7 ║
║     9 ║ red    ║ Amanda ║    4 ║
║    10 ║ black  ║ Luke   ║    8 ║
╚═══════╩════════╩════════╩══════╝
```

The column `head` stores the index of parent node. It will create a tree as below:

[image: Tree Structure]

And each node can have 0+ children (not limited to 2).

I want to find another person with the same color when I select a person. There are 3 rules:

1. Select the nearest person if he is on the same stem
2. If no one is selected, select the nearest person within the same tree
3. Return `None` if no one can be selected

For example, Katy will match with Tom. Since there are no more red color in the same stem with Betty, Amanda will be selected.

Is there any way rather than brute force all combination to get the answer?

Comment: and what is expected result(`dataframe` / `dict` etc)? could you provide result example?

Comment: I expected to have `pd.DataFrame` / list of tuples which contains 2 columns. They are the 2 paired names (or indices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the technique of network analysis, not sure if it best suits your case.

The idea is simple:

1. Make a network graph
2. Find all other people, which I call them candidates, with the same colour as your selected person
3. Check if the candidates and the selected person are connected in the network (i.e. whether there is a path between the candidates and the selected person)
4. Find the candidate with shortest path

Here is my code

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import shortest_path, has_path


# Data
df_str = """
index,colour,name,head
0,red,Tom,0
1,blue,Lucy,0
2,green,Peter,1
3,red,Katy,1
4,green,Sam,4
5,orange,Linda,2
6,blue,Robert,4
7,brown,James,6
8,red,Betty,7
9,red,Amanda,4
10,black,Luke,8
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str), sep=",")


# Function to find the closest person with the same colour as the person with `id0`
def find_same_colour(id0, df):
    # Create network
    g = nx.Graph()
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        g.add_node(row['index'], colour=row['colour'])
        if row['index'] != row['head']:
            g.add_edge(row['index'], row['head'])
    # List out candidates
    colour = df.loc[df['index'].values == id0, 'colour'].values[0]
    candidates = df.loc[(df['colour'].values == colour) & (df['index'].values != id0), 'index'].values
    # Initialise searching
    target = None
    l_max = df.shape[0] + 2
    # Search
    for i in candidates:
        if has_path(g, id0, i):
            path = shortest_path(g, id0, i)
            if len(path) < l_max:
                target = i
    return target


for i in df['index'].values:
    print(i, find_same_colour(i, df), sep='-')
```

And here is the output,

```
# 0-3
# 1-None
# 2-None
# 3-0
# 4-None
# 5-None
# 6-None
# 7-None
# 8-9
# 9-8
# 10-None
```